# "The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created" during installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation-package

A few days ago I had a crash of my computer and since then i am unable to succesfully install Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

During the setup a error screen comes up with nothing but a message "The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created". Searching for this only results in the same error message but only after installation where Visual Studio cannot be launched.

This is different for me since I am able to run it. But i am unable to e.g. create ASP.net VMC projects. Some things run fine. Others just fail at the start.

Uninstalling the whole shizzle separatly came to that the error may be in the SQL server package. Since this error came up while uninstalling the SQL shizzle.

I'm not sure if this error is a common issue, but it's really annoying since I will be learning ASP.net VMC4 at school for the coming 5 months.

This is the error message i get. I only moved the window a little bit the let you take a look at the package.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2DiJ.jpg

Below there is a fragment of log files where installation packages failed. Hope they are handy.

```
[1638:169C][2013-09-06T10:48:00]: Applying execute package: silverlight5_DRT, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\DEB5078B60B74431E2830831EB48DF129CB32932\packages\Silverlight\5.0_DRT\Silverlight_Developer.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\DEB5078B60B74431E2830831EB48DF129CB32932\packages\Silverlight\5.0_DRT\Silverlight_Developer.exe" /q /ignorewarnings'
[1638:169C][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: Error 0x800705de: Process returned error: 0x5de
[1638:169C][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: Error 0x800705de: Failed to execute EXE package.
[00F4:1730][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: Error 0x800705de: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[00F4:1730][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: silverlight5_DRT MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 20688896  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 94208
[00F4:1730][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: MUX:  Return Code:0x800705DE Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[00F4:1730][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023394 (0x800705DE), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Repair, Package Id=silverlight5_DRT
[00F4:1730][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: Applied non-vital package: silverlight5_DRT, encountered error: 0x800705de. Continuing...
[1638:169C][2013-09-06T10:48:03]: Applying execute package: rs_addon_msi, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1DB43E5A-2F24-4F51-92B0-A2C0EBF5C742}v11.1.2802.16\packages\Reporting Services\RVAddon.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VS_SETUP="1"'
```

Comment: I just uninstalled the Ultimate and i am installing the professional now.

Comment: Professional gives same error. Please help!

Comment: You have serious permissions problems which points to system integrity problems.  You will have to resolve your system problems before we can help you.   I would just reinstall Windows considering the image is corrupt.

Comment: @ramhound is it possible these system integrity issues could be a result of the system crash is had? Since I was unable to get into windows for a last backup I decided to not format my HDD and keep a copy of my old windows in windows.old

Comment: The crash I had was a ramdisk-driver which got corrupted after a virus broke down the house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by formatting my pc and starting all over again. I still don't know the real problem but this solved it.